# define vertex in python iGraph by x,y coordinates

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I am trying to define a vertex in python using igprah lybrari. When i try to define it as a single integer there is not problem, but if i want to define a vertex as a (x-coordinate,y-coordinate) and add an edge between 2 verteces defined like this then i have an error:

```
TypeError: only numbers, vertex names or igraph.Vertex objects can be converted to vertex IDs
```

So i tried to create namedtupel

```
Coordinates = namedtuple('Coordinates','x,y')
firstVertex = Coordinates(1,2)
secondVertex = Coordinates(3,4)
```

and then i tried to use implicit conversion during adding the edge between those verteces but it doesnt work.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Coordinates'
```

Is there any way how to define vertex with x,y coordinates and use it in igraph lybrary? Or is there a better way how to work with this kind of graphs, where i need to have my verteces defined with coordinates?? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

igraph supports only integers or strings as vertex IDs. If you need to store any additional data related to a vertex, you must store it as vertex attributes. E.g.:

```
>>> g = Graph(3)
>>> g.vs[0]["coordinates"] = (1, 2)
>>> g.vs[1]["coordinates"] = (3, 4)
```

This will assign `(1, 2)` to the `"coordinates"` vertex attribute of vertex 0, and `(3, 4)` to the "coordinates" vertex attribute of vertex 1. Depending on what you want to achieve, it might be better to use two separate vertex attributes (`x` and `y`) because these are automatically used as layout coordinates when plotting the graph. E.g.:

```
>>> g.vs[0]["x"], g.vs[0]["y"] = 1, 2
```

There is also a shorthand notation for assigning the values of a vertex attribute for all the vertices:

```
>>> g.vs["x"] = [1, 2, 3]
>>> g.vs["y"] = [2, 4, 6]
>>> g.vs[0]["x"], g.vs[0]["y"]
(1, 2)
>>> g.vs[1]["x"], g.vs[1]["y"]
(2, 4)
>>> g.vs[2]["x"], g.vs[2]["y"]
(3, 6)
```